# How to authenticate HTTP cloud function from external server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have created an HTTP Google Cloud function in Node.js. Now I want to invoke it from a backend service running on another server. How can I get an authentication token for it?

I can find references on authenticating function-to-function calls, but I can't find any references on calling secure cloud functions from an external server.

Probably I'm missing something in the documentation, but I can't understand it much because of its simple use cases, which can't be implemented with real-life projects.

How can I get an authentication token and call the secure cloud function from an external server running on Node.js?

**Updates**:

I moved to pub/sub and converted the cloud function to an event-triggered function, as that suits my use case best.

Now I'm using a service account to authenticate requests.

Comment: Is the server external to Google Cloud? Is it on Azure? AWS? Other?

Comment: Currently, it's AWS.  What I'm trying to do is I wanted to trigger my HTTP cloud function from my Node JS server running on any other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "any machine" is wide. In fact there is 2 solutions:

- The most secure is when you are on AWS or Azure (and of course on GCP). You can use the current server identity (on AWS and Azure) and [use workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation) to match this identity with a service account and use it
- The less secure is to [generate a service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete) on a service account and store it **securely** on the machine (the securely is difficult, that's why it's less secure). Use the the service account key file to generate a token

In both case, when you are authenticated as a service account, you must generate an identity token with the correct audience to call the Cloud Functions service. (and the service account must have the CLoud Functions invoker role also)